# How to "anchor" SWT widgets?

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, swt

I'm trying to make a simple browser with the SWT library. I'm having a problem though trying to get objects to anchor to the top left and such.

I'm using Eclipse and using the layout assistant I set the anchors to top-left and all the other options.

Basically I want the browser control to auto size. Thank you! :D

The layout type I am using is the Form Layout (It was suggested on the SWT help page for using anchors.)

Comment: The question is too broad. In general `FormLayout` is probably what you want, but in order to provide precise help you should be more precise in your question. Try posting some (simple) code and describing how the result differs from what you want.

Comment: @E-Riz
Basically I'm trying to get a Browser to stay linked to the sides of the actual Window. If I was to paste code it would just be the code that Eclipse generated which I didn't think would be that helpful. But, I'll provide it anyways :)

http://pastebin.com/pnLHptc0

The code makes a window and runs fine, but when you try expanding the window, the browser object stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you're trying to do (attach the widget to the sides of its parent), it's enough to use the single-argument constructor of `FormAttachment`. This works:

```
fd_browser.top = new FormAttachment(0);
fd_browser.left = new FormAttachment(0);
fd_browser.bottom = new FormAttachment(100);
fd_browser.right = new FormAttachment(100);
```

What that says is "attach the top edge to the 0% vertical postion of the container," "attach the left edge to the 0% horizontal position," "attach the bottom edge to the 100% vertical position of the container," and "attach the right edge to the 100% position of the container." In other words, the top and left edges will be at the container origin + 0 and the bottom and right edges will be at the container origin + 100% of the container size. It sounds complex in words but I think it's actually very intuitive.

Using the two-argument c'tor as your code does, is specifying hard-coded offsets from the container's 0,0 position (450 down and 845 across), which is essentially telling the Browser widget to be fixed size. Offsets in FormLayout are really only useful for setting margins or, um, offsets from edges of the container or other widgets. :-)

I'd suggest read the JavaDocs for FormAttachment and FormLayout again - once you "get" it I think it will be easy for you to use. There are also probably some examples on the [SWT Snippets page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! No "RTFM(Documentation)", you gave an example, and even tips! Thank you for being one of those **nice** people on SO!